# Is というのだ similar to "in addition"? Or it is "they said"?

Tags: grammar, set-phrases

1. まだ十香の件にさえ納得がいっていない様子の折紙である。そんなところにもう一人精霊が現れた**というのである**。それは不審に思うだろう。だが、かといって＜ラタトスク＞のことを説明するわけにもいかない。
2. 『ーー君の説明だけでは、信憑性が足りなっかたのだよ。何しろ自己蘇生能力に……精霊の力を吸収する能力**というんだ**。にわかには信じられん』
3. ただでさえ、女子の手作りクッキーをいただくなんてのは、他の男子たちの嫉妬の的だ。
   しかもそれが、転入直後から、彼女にしたい女子ランキングを駆け上がった(と噂の)あの夜刀神十香のものだ**というのである**。

Hi. Please have a look at the three examples. According to some people, all three bold parts mean "they said". But I think the bold parts in the three examples are some kind of emphasis----they function as "add", which is similar to the English equivalent "even", "in addition" or "furthermore". So in a manner of speaking, they are similar to the other expression "ときたものだ".

What do you think? Does my thinking make sense? Or should I take them literally as "they said"?

Thank you in advance.